# What should i do if my computer can't run ubuntu

Tags: boot, acer, aspire

I downloaded both 12.04LTS and 13.04 and installed it on my computer,an acer aspire 3005wlci, but when the computer starts up it fails to boot. What should I do for it. Any suggestion is a good one. Thanks in Advance

Comment: What happens when you try to boot from a Live USB Flash Drive created with unetbootin - are you able to boot? With a machine of the specs I see for the 3005wlci, personally, I would use http://xubuntu.org or http://lubuntu.net instead of standard Ubuntu for those derivative distros are lighter and work better when you don't have a lot of memory, yet can run LibreOffice, GIMP and other full-featured apps.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running it? You're lacking key details here... I installed using a USB and on the first time, that failed for me. You should try to re-burn the iso to whatever you're trying to install it on, and then come back.

Back? Well, it could be that your computer can't actually run Ubuntu. This can sometimes happen due to performance, but do not give up. There are lighter versions of Ubuntu for you, such as Kubuntu, xubuntu, etc. There is linux mint, debian, etc. If you find your self wanting to try one of those, you can always Google it and it should bring you straight to the downloads page for the OS.